# Label overlapping with Checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried putting padding margin on left side of bot input element as well as label, neither helps. Could you help me with aligning the label correctly? thanks!

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-checkbox">
                <input id="activateSocialMediaTrial" name="activateSocialMediaTrial" asp-for="ActivateSocialMediaTrial" type="checkbox" style="padding: 15px; margin:15px" />
                <label for="activateSocialMediaTrial" style="white-space: nowrap">Sign me up for a <b>free 30 days trial of social media management</b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

```
.input-checkbox label {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any checkbox plugin that makes your checkbox look like this?

Comment: Can you show the styling in your inspector? I posted your code here: https://codepen.io/arlcode/pen/oaYeEN and it works just fine, I'm assuming there's a Bootstrap default that is overwriting it.

Comment: Logically adding `padding-left:75px` (*approximate value guess*) should help the situation. For more you would have to show the css for the input as well as the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the margin of `input` to `margin:15px` that is causing it to move from its intended position, as in bootstrap the `input:checkbox` is having `margin:-1.25em` so you are moving it from its position.

Comment: thanks. margin you mentioned is already there in above snippet. Did you miss to scroll right ;-)

Comment: yes I have seen it, that's what I pointed out, you have added `margin:15px` whereas the default style has `margin-left:-1.25rem`, so the checkbox is being dragged back over the label by the 15px.